# Linker looking for library with lib prefix, although not using -l flag in QtCreator / qmake

Tags: qt, linker, qt-creator, qmake

I am trying to include a library to my project, which I compiled myself. The outcome of that compilation is simply a "fastrtps-1.9.lib" and a "fastcdr-1.0.lib" + include folders.

Now when I try to include it in qmake, it always throws an error LNK1104 "libfastcdr-1.0.lib" cannot be opened...

```
:-1: Fehler: LNK1104: Datei "libfastcdr-1.0.lib" kann nicht geöffnet werden.
```

I understand that the -l Flag surrounds the lib name with lib and .lib/.a but this is the way I included the library:

```
win32: LIBS += $$PWD/../../../../_programme/FastRTPSv1.9/install/fastcdr/lib/fastcdr-1.0.lib

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../_programme/FastRTPSv1.9/install/fastcdr/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../_programme/FastRTPSv1.9/install/fastcdr/include

win32: LIBS += $$PWD/../../../../_programme/FastRTPSv1.9/install/fastrtps/lib/fastrtps-1.9.lib

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../_programme/FastRTPSv1.9/install/fastrtps/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../_programme/FastRTPSv1.9/install/fastrtps/include
```

Why does it look for the lib prefix??

Comment: Maybe the library's headers have [`pragma comment lib`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/comment-c-cpp?view=vs-2019#lib) directives containing that hard-coded name?

Comment: i found the following in one of the 217 headers: #pragma comment(lib, EPROSIMA_LIB_PREFIX EPRO[....]".lib") But why does it not throw lib prefix then when I compile the library? What do I need to do, to get the lib prefixes? Can I just copy and rename the lib files?

Comment: Renaming the lib files should work. You could also try to define something to make the name in that `#pragma comment` match whatever it is you have on disk.

Comment: I found the correct binary files of that library now, so I don't need to compile it myself. The binaries include all lib files (with or without prefix). But it still doesnt work. Using -l flags I get LNK2005 "already defined" errors. When using absolute paths without flags it wants me to include both the lib prefixed one and the one without, and then gives me an "already defined" LNK2005 error too. Is that a problem with the library?